# Dataset.WriteXml Method writes an additional table instead of overwritting

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, writexml

I have a dataset in my hand with one table only and I want to write it to the current xml file. When I write it, it creates a new table and add it to it instead of overwritting. everytime I write it, It multiples the number of tables by 2.

```
Globals.ds.WriteXml(Application.StartupPath + "\\Settings.xml");
```

How do I overwrite to the same xml file to save the parameters?

Comment: Use other overloads of WriteXml method e.g. the one with FileStream. This way you have control over how that file gets created.

Comment: I tried with all other overload methods with different parameters. I used Stream and FileStream also.

Comment: I think there was a bug in .NET Framework about this because I moved another xml file name "Setting - Copy.xml" and It works proparly now. So it seems to be a bug.